# Image on button displaying incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I've got a bit of a strange thing going on in my project. I have a series of buttons that when clicked should display images. The code is pretty straightforward. The method on the view controller is:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {


    NSUInteger senderID = [sender tag];

    Photos *pic = [[Photos alloc]init];

    pic.images = [pic createListOfImages];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [pic.images objectAtIndex:senderID];
    [sender setImage: buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

I have a class called Photos with a property called images which is a MutableArray and a method called createListOfImages that initialises the images.

The problem I get is visual, I have added two pictures. The first shows the what should show (which I get by loading the picture on the storyboard as a background Image) and the second shows what I get when I run it on the simulator.

Picture 1: [what I see on the storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h26lt.png)

Picture 2: [what shows on the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHnD1.png)

Has anyone had a problem like this? Is it code related or to do with the resolution of the picture? I can post the whole code if necessary. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this put these lines into you function

```
[sender setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```